# how to update android applications when I distributing the application sending the apk to the users? (MAUI)

Tags: c#, maui

I have an application that I distribute to the users sending the the apk.

With the application I include some MAUI assets (some text files).

The application use the store to store some configuration data.

The problem is that when I try to install a new version, if there is an actual version installed, it says it is updating the application, thats ok.

But I have realized that the update is not done correctly, because if in the new version I have a new control, it is not shown. It is needed to unistall the actual version an install the new one.

The problem is that the configuration of the user is lost, so the user has to configure again the application.

Is it possible to update the application from the apk file? Which would it be the correct process or way to ensure the update is correct (showing new controls)?

Or perhaps it could be possible to store the configuration in some place to can load when the application is installed, try to load the saved configuration? But I would like, if this is a possible solution, to store it in a safe place, because some data is sensible data.

In summary, I would like to know how to update the application from a new apk and to make it a easy way for the user.

Thanks.

Comment: Android should allow you to install a new version over the old version and maintain any local user data.  If this is not working then you need to look at the logs to determine why.